# Stored Procedure Parameter with FORMSOF and Thesaurus (SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTableColumns]
       @search_phrase varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    from SearchTableColumn stc 
    where contains(*, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, @search_phrase)') 
    order by stc.weight desc
END
```

The stored procedure was created without any problems in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2. If I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
exec GetTableColumns 'instrument'
```

I got no records returned.

However, if I query the database with the following SQL,

```
SELECT * 
from SearchTableColumn stc 
where contains(*, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, instrument)') 
order by stc.weight desc
```

I got records returned.

So I am wondering if something I am missing in the stored procedure which prevents the records from being returned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for a literal `'FORMSOF(Thesaurus,@search_phrase)'` in your table.

Try setting the search value using the passed in param:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTableColumns]
@search_phrase varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @search varchar(120) = 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus,' + @search_phrase + ')' 

    SELECT  * 
    from    SearchTableColumn stc 
    where   contains(*, @search) 
    order by stc.weight desc

END
```